# Какое регулярное выражение разбивает текст на массив по запятым и переносам строк?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Необходимо для preg_replace (php). Спасибо.

Comment: так по "запятым **и** переносам" или "запятым **или** переносам"? В ответах ниже вариант "или", а в вопросе - "и".

Comment: "и" ) но уже не так актуально ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_split("/\n|,/", $text)
```

Comment: Не воспримите как умничанье, а как желание помочь Вам:  
эффективнее в таких ситуациях делать символьный класс `[\n,]`

Comment: @ReinRaus да я бы рад услышать совет, но хотелось бы также узнать, почему эффективнее :)

Comment: Движок регексов естественно предварительно преобразует выражение в более удобный для себя вид.  
В выражении `[\n,]` движок просто последовательно обрабатывает символ за символом.  
В выражении `\n|,` движок каждый раз не встретив `\n` создает точку возврата в которую нужно вернуться, если ни одна из следующих альтернатив не совпадет. Сохранение точки возврата и возврат в нее более затратно, чем последовательный просмотр символов.  
Как-то так.  
P.S. Это по теории регулярных выражений, если движок использует грамотную оптимизацию, то он сам внутри себя преобразует `\n|,` в `[\n,]`

Comment: @ReinRaus хм, интересненько, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
split(/[\n,]/)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное ) Путаюсь еще с регулярками

Comment: @aysergeev, заметно :) Вам предлагают решение для JavaScript, а не PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php ну почему же...